# This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 70

Tags: node.js, electron

I was trying to build a native module for electron (node.js). But after building it when try to use it my project i get 'this module was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 70. Please try re-compiling or re-installing' error.

I have try a lot of way, but didn't able to solve it. Also i have checked on the node.js release logs, no where found any version that includes NODE_MODULE_VERSION 70.

Comment: This is neither a duplicate questions nor already has an answer. Node release with module version 70 is nowhere to be found.

Comment: For anyone wondering, this (v70) is the NODE_MODULE_VERSION required by electron v5: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/abi_version_registry.json

Comment: @Abdillah / Jabed - Did you find any solution of this ? I am also struggling with this issue.

Comment: Yes, I modified neon (in my case) to compile with the correct headers (for v70): https://github.com/neon-bindings/neon/compare/master...Abdillah:electron-support. If you use neon, you may also look at https://neon-bindings.com/docs/electron-apps.

Comment: @Abdillah - OMG !! i am pulling my hair out. well, finally i am able to resolve it. I reinstalled all dependencies in specific order. electron, node-gyp, serialport. Whooaa !!..